# Use of Draper Point as a reference for resistance-thermometer measurements

Tags: electrical-resistance, thermal-radiation

In Stefan's law experiment we know the emissive power of a black body is directly proportional to the 4th power of its absolute temperature, that is $P=\sigma T^4$.
Now in order to verify this law we assume that the emissive power is depended on temperature but to the nth power, so $P=\sigma T^n$

Now we have to show that $n$ is close to $4$.

Now to experiment that we use a set up where a torch bulb is present and the filament is assumed to a blackbody so there we can change current flow $I$ voltage $V$ and from there we can get the power that is $P=IV$,
and resistance $R=\frac{V}{I}$.

And as we know the resistance is depended on temperature 
$R=R_o(1+\alpha T+\beta T^2)$
Where $\alpha$,$\beta$ are temperature coefficients of resistance .

$R_o$ is resistance at 0℃ 
But we can not get the value of $R_o$ because we don't have that kind of system to produce $0\rm^\circ C$.
So we make a trick 
$\frac{R}{R_d}= \frac{1+\alpha T+\beta T^2}{1+\alpha T^\prime+\beta T^{\prime 2}}$
Where we Rd is resistance at Draper point which is almost equal to $525\rm^\circ 
C$. Then using the reference of Draper point we can calculate the corresponding temperature and show that $n$ is approximately equal to 4, thus the Stefan law is verified.

But my question is why we use the Draper point at $525\rm^\circ C$?
Why not at $626\rm^\circ C$ or anything else?
I mean we have to take a reference resistance so that we can calculate the value of temperature 
As we don't know value of resistance at $0\rm^\circ C$.

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out the resistance of the light bulb $R$ as a function of the temperature $t$ in degree Celsius depends on three parameters: $\alpha, \beta$ and $R_o$ the resistance of the light bulb at $0^\circ$C.
You will use this relationship to find the temperature of the light bulb knowing the resistance of the light bulb.

I assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are known constants so that all that you need to do is to find $R_o$.
As you point out it is impractical to find $R_o$ directly so what is needed is to measure the resistance of the light bulb at one other known temperature.

The temperature which is chosen is the [Draper temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draper_point) which is a known temperature of the light bulb filament at which you can see visible light coming from the light bulb.
So you need to go into a dark room and increase the power supplied to the light bulb and note the value of the voltage across and the current through the light bulb when you can just see the filament glowing dull red.
The filament is then at the known Draper temperature and so you can now evaluate $R_o$.

Why not $626\;^\circ$C? How would you know the filament was at that temperature?  The beauty of the Draper temperature is that the onset of visible light occurs at that temperature for many materials including the tungsten of which you light bulb filament is made.